# json object to <p> formatting issue

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have tried to add my JSON object value to `<p>` but the formatting is different.

in `console.log` looks like this 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA9MF.png)

```
LINE INTERFACE UNIT,OMNITRON DX-64 LIU
Item                                : UNIT,LINE INTERFACE
Reference,Manufacturer              : 0002-03020
Manufacturer                        : OMNITRONICS
Model                               : DX-64 LIU
Supplier                            : NESSCOINVSAT LTD.
Item                                : LINE INTERFACE UNIT
```

but my HTML view looks like this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilxhs.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `<pre>` tag inside `<p>`

Answer (score 2):

You do not provide quite enough information about what your HTML/CSS looks like. By default, HTML will collapse all spaces unless specified otherwise in CSS or with the `<pre>` tag. However, your spaces are not getting collapsed which means that you have probably specified something in your CSS to not collapse spaces. For example, you may be using the `white-space` property.

In that case, the main difference is the font you are using. In the console it is using a `monospace` font where every character has the same width. You HTML view is not using a monospace font and therefore some characters are wider than others (eg. `W` is wider than `i`). Try setting your HTML to using a monospace font such as by adding the following to your CSS

```
font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace
```

As was mentioned, you could also use `<pre>` as that doesn't collapse whitespace and it also sets the font to monospace. However, I tend to find a purely CSS approach much less clunky than having to add a `<pre>` inside each of your `<p>` elements. Though ultimately, you should probably be using a `<div>` rather than `<p>` as `<p>` should only be used for paragraphs and in your case it is not a paragraph.

Here is an example code snippet:

```css
div#details {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace
}
```

```html
<div id="details">
LINE INTERFACE UNIT,OMNITRON DX-64 LIU
Item                                : UNIT,LINE INTERFACE
Reference,Manufacturer              : 0002-03020
Manufacturer                        : OMNITRONICS
Model                               : DX-64 LIU
Supplier                            : NESSCOINVSAT LTD.
Item                                : LINE INTERFACE UNIT
</div>
```